# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I've created a GUI using wxFormBuilder that should allow a user to enter the names of "visitors to a business" into a list and then click one of two buttons to return the most frequent and least frequent visitors to the business.

I created an earlier version that, unfortunately, gave me the range of visitors, rather than the name of the most/least frequent visitor. I've attached a screenshot of the GUI I've created to help add a little clarity to the issue ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GHbK.jpg ).

A new code version takes a different tack than the earlier version, and I can't get it to throw anything. Instead, I keep receiving this error:

**ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence**

In relation to this line:

**self.txtResults.Value = k.index(max(v))**

```
import wx
import myLoopGUI
import commands

class MyLoopFrame(myLoopGUI.MyFrame1):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        myLoopGUI.MyFrame1.__init__(self, parent)

    def clkAddData(self,parent):
        if len(self.txtAddData.Value) != 0:
            try:
                myname = str(self.txtAddData.Value)
                self.listMyData.Append(str(myname))
            except:
                wx.MessageBox("This has to be a name!")            
        else:
            wx.MessageBox("This can't be empty")




    def clkFindMost(self, parent):
        self.listMyData = []
        unique_names = set(self.listMyData)
        frequencies = {}
        for name in unique_names:
            if frequencies.get[name]:
                frequencies[name] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[name] = 0

        v = list(frequencies.values())
        k = list(frequencies.keys())
        self.txtResults.Value = k.index(max(v))


    def clkFindLeast(self, parent):
        unique_names = set(self.listMyData)
        frequencies = {}
        for name in unique_names:
            if frequencies.get(name):
                frequencies[name] += 1
            else:
                frequencies[name] = 0

        v = list(frequencies.values())
        k = list(frequencies.keys())
        self.txtResults.Value = k.index(min(v))

myApp = wx.App(False)
myFrame = MyLoopFrame(None)
myFrame.Show()
myApp.MainLoop()
```

Comment: When `len(v) == 0`, in `clkFindMost`, `max(v)` raises `ValueError`.

Comment: this type of error comes when you pass empty list in max(). So check if list is available than pass it into the max

Answer (score 68):

Pass a `default` value which can be returned by `max` if the sequence is empty:

```
max(v, default=0)
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me.

Comment: This solution is very helpful for me.

Comment: Work on 3, but max in python 2 doesn't have `default` argument

Comment: this is decent if you know `v` has no `None` items. Otherwise you'll receive an error of: `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Answer (score 19):

Since you are always initialising `self.listMyData` to an empty list in `clkFindMost` your code will always lead to this error* because after that both `unique_names` and `frequencies` are empty iterables, so fix this.

Another thing is that since you're iterating over a set in that method then calculating frequency makes no sense as set contain only unique items, so frequency of each item is always going to be 1.

Lastly `dict.get` is a method not a list or dictionary so you can't use `[]` with it:

Correct way is:

```
if frequencies.get(name):
```

And Pythonic way is:

```
if name in frequencies:
```

The Pythonic way to get the frequency of items is to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter   #Add this at the top of file.

def clkFindMost(self, parent):

        #self.listMyData = []   
        if self.listMyData:
           frequencies = Counter(self.listMyData)
           self.txtResults.Value = max(frequencies, key=frequencies.get)
        else:
           self.txtResults.Value = ''
```

---

`max()` and `min()` throw such error when an empty iterable is passed to them. You can check the length of `v` before calling `max()` on it.

```
>>> lst = []
>>> max(lst)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    max(lst)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>> if lst:
    mx = max(lst)
else:
    #Handle this here
```

If you are using it with an iterator then you need to consume the iterator first before calling `max()` on it because boolean value of iterator is always `True`, so we can't use `if` on them directly:

```
>>> it = iter([])
>>> bool(it)
True
>>> lst = list(it)
>>> if lst:
       mx = max(lst)
    else:
      #Handle this here
```

Good news is starting from Python 3.4 you will be able to [specify an optional return value](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#other-language-changes) for `min()` and `max()` in case of empty iterable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Had a similar issue when I closed my PyQt application and max was called on an empty list.

Answer (score 7):

When the length of v will be zero, it'll give you the value error.

You should check the length or you should check the list first whether it is none or not.

```
if list:
    k.index(max(list))
```

or

```
len(list)== 0
```

Answer (score 7):

in one line,

`v = max(v) if v else None`

```
>>> v = []
>>> max(v)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
>>> v = max(v) if v else None
>>> v
>>>
```

Comment: I often do this `max(seq or [0])`, where 0 is the default returned in case the sequence is empty.

Comment: so what do you want if max([0]) is 0? if you want none add one more else if

`v = max(v) if v else None if not max(v) else None`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. I use `max(seq or [0])` only if I want the default to be zero, i.e. if I use the result in an arithmetic operation. If I want the default to be None, I would use `max(seq) if seq else None`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was iterating over a list of lists where some of them were empty. I fixed this by adding this preprocessing step:

```
tfidfLsNew = [x for x in tfidfLs if x != []]
```

the len() of the original was 3105, and the len() of the latter was 3101, implying that four of my lists were completely empty. After this preprocess my max() min() etc. were functioning again.