# Function returns a proper dictionary at first, returns an empty one on later runs

Tags: python-3.x

The problem I'm working on requires me to implement a program to display hotels with avg. ratings, which are later on checked by the user.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d7va219cqcdccsl/reviews.txt?dl=0 file for reviews.txt

https://www.dropbox.com/s/djbpox373l83m3b/hotels.txt?dl=0 file for hotels.txt

First function on the code below gives results that I want on the first run, however returns 2 empty dictionaries on later ones.

```
from google.colab import files
    files.upload()

hotels = open("hotels.txt") # id \t hotel
reviews = open("reviews.txt") # user \t id \t rating


def hotelDicts(fileHotel, fileReview):

    dictHotelID = {}
    dictHotelPoint = {}
    dictReview = {}

    for line in fileHotel:

        line = line.strip("\n").split("\t")

        hotelID = line[0]
        hotelName = line[1]

        dictHotelID[hotelID] = hotelName

        dictHotelPoint[hotelName] = [0, 0]

    for line in fileReview:

        line = line.strip("\n").split("\t")

        user = line[0]
        hotelID = line[1]
        rating = int(line[2])

        if hotelID in dictHotelID:
            dictHotelPoint[dictHotelID[hotelID]][0] += rating
            dictHotelPoint[dictHotelID[hotelID]][1] += 1

        # print(dictHotelPoint[dictHotelID[hotelID]][0])

        if user not in dictReview:
            dictReview[user] = 1
        elif user in dictReview:
            dictReview[user] += 1        

    for hotel in dictHotelPoint:

        total = dictHotelPoint[hotel][0]
        count = dictHotelPoint[hotel][1]

        if count > 0:
            total = total / count
            dictHotelPoint[hotel] = "%.1f"%total

        elif count == 0:
            dictHotelPoint[hotel] = 0

    return dictHotelPoint, dictReview

def userHotel(dictHotel, dictReview):

    maxUser = max(dictReview)
    maxHotel = max(dictHotel)

    print("The user who posted the most reviews is", maxUser)
    print("The best hotel:", maxHotel)

    while True:

        hotelInput = input("Please enter a hotel name: ")

        if hotelInput in dictHotel:
            if dictHotel[hotelInput] != 0:
                print("The average rating of the hotel:",   dictHotel[hotelInput])
            else:
                print("Nobody has rated for this hotel yet.")
        elif hotelInput not in dictHotel:
            print("Hotel name does not exist in the database.")
        elif hotelInput == "quit":
            break

hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)

userHotel(hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)[0], hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)[1])
```

({'Alila Manggis': '4.0',
  'Aman': '3.0',
  'Belmond Grand Hotel Timeo': 0,
  'Brewery Gulch Inn': 0,
  'Esperanza': 0,
  'Farm at Cape Kidnappers': 0,
  'Four Seasons Resort': 0,
  'Hewing Hotel': '4.3',
  'Hotel Maria Cristina': 0,
  'Katikies': '4.0',
  'Pendry': '4.5',
  'Planters Inn': '4.5',
  'Qualia': '2.0',
  'Sol y Luna': '2.0',
  'Taj Diplomatic Enclave': '5.0',
  'The Beekman': 0,
  'The Cloister': 0,
  'The Lanesborough': '2.5',
  'The Setai': '2.0',
  'Triple Creek Ranch': '3.0'},
 {'carefreeted': 3,
  'dotingoutlaw': 1,
  'excitedcarrier': 1,
  'gargantuantrusty': 2,
  'imaginaryscooner': 1,
  'kookybob': 4,
  'noteworthymom': 2,
  'preciouslegend': 1,
  'prejucidednorman': 1,
  'prejudicednorman': 1,
  'priceyscout': 1,
  'uniquehombre': 1,
  'yearlysecretariat': 1})

Expected outcome for the lists hotels and reviews are these. The first call of the function returns these, but returns two empty dictionaries when run for a second time on Google Colab. The last line gives a value error:

```
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

first off, you probably dont want to call the functions like this:

```
    hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)

userHotel(hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)[0], hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)[1])
```

as what you're doing is running the function multiple times, it would be better to call it like this:

```
dict1, dict2 = hotelDicts(hotels, reviews)
output = userHotel(dict1,dict2)
```

thatl help with consistency for debugging.

also here:

```
if hotelID in dictHotelID:
    dictHotelPoint[dictHotelID[hotelID]][0] += rating
    dictHotelPoint[dictHotelID[hotelID]][1] += 1
```

you probably want "]" after dictHotelID

and where youre adding users to the dict, you could use the dictionary.extend() method:

a.extend(b)

this also looks a bit off:

```
if count > 0:
    total = total / count
    dictHotelPoint[hotel] = "%.1f"%total
```

maybe :

```
if count > 0:
    total = total / count
    dictHotelPoint[hotel] = float(total)
```

I can't seem to see anything obvious that might be causing the empty sequence so sorry i cant be of more help. this thread seems to have more info:

[ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151669/valueerror-max-arg-is-an-empty-sequence)