# .append() method won't work in my defined function

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, append, percentile

I'm trying to define a function to get the percentile that corresponds to a number, given a distribution.

This is how I defined the function:

```
def minimum_percentile(sample, number):
    percentiles = []
    for i in range(100):
        percentile = np.percentile(sample, i)
        if percentile.any() >= number:
            percentiles.append(percentile)
        else:
            continue
    return min(percentiles)
```

When I call the function:

```
minimum_percentile(packages_means, 33.1388)
```

The error I get has to do with the fact that my function doesn't seem to populate the empty list, getting this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-9923821f6175> in <module>
----> 1 minimum_percentile(packages_means, 33.1388)

<ipython-input-63-955dedc13fde> in minimum_percentile(sample, number)
      5         if percentile.any() >= number:
      6             percentiles.append(percentile)
----> 7     return min(percentiles)

ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You haven't appended anything to the (empty) `percentiles` list, and the reason why you haven't done so is probably because your `percentile.any() >= number` is not doing what you think it is.

Comment: I added the .any() function because I received another error message before, and it told me to use either .any() or .all(), I already tried .all() as well

Comment: [ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151669) have good answers.

Comment: Append is working just fine. You need to debug your code. This is exactly why an MCVE is important. Showing a function you wrote is pointless if you don't show how it's called.

Comment: Change `if percentile.any() >= number:` to `if (percentile >= number).any():`

Comment: Based on your answer, I am voting to close since it looks like you misread the docs about which way percentile sorts.

Answer (score -1):

I played a bit with your code and it looks like the min() function doesn't work because your list "percentiles" is empty. So i added a part where i checked if the list is empty the program shoud return "None" and here is what i got:

```
import numpy as np
def minimum_percentile(sample, number):
    percentiles = []
    for i in range(100):
        percentile = np.percentile(sample, i)
        if percentile >= number:
            percentiles.append(percentile)

        else:
            continue
    if not percentiles:
        return "None"
    else:
        return min(percentiles)
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
minimum_percentile(l, 2.5)
```

> > 2.52