# Python max arg is empty sequence on non empty list

Tags: python

I get *ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence* from this lines of code:

```
result = {}

ids = [...] # may be empty
objects_from_ids = func_to_fetch_objects(delivery_ids) # returns empty list, if ids are empty, or list of objects, with corresponding ids

if objects_from_ids:
   result["max_dt"] = max(d["dt"] for d in objects_from_ids) # Here comes error
```

Can anyone explain me, why this might happen?
I`ve read answers about default value for cases with empty sequences, but want to understand this case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151669/valueerror-max-arg-is-an-empty-sequence)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objects_from_ids` might be a list of empty objects or the error is in the `func_to_fetch_objects()`

Try printing there values inside the if clause to know what's going inside.

Comment: I figured out, what was the problem, ty for Empty Object suggestion.